# ValueError: Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed` while training model from spacy

Tags: gpu, spacy, cupy

I have tried finding solution from other similar errors but couldn't solve it, and I don't know what the error is about.

```
UserWarning: Can't initialize NVML   warnings.warn("Can't initialize NVML") ℹ Saving to output directory: . ℹ Using GPU: 0 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in
_run_module_as_main   File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 87, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/typer/main.py", line 532, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 54, in train_cli
    train(config_path, output_path, use_gpu=use_gpu, overrides=overrides)   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/cli/train.py", line 76, in train
    setup_gpu(use_gpu)   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 272, in setup_gpu
    require_gpu(use_gpu)   File "/home/nikita/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/thinc/util.py", line 230, in require_gpu
    raise ValueError("Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed") ValueError: Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed
```

I have already installed cupy.

Comment: "Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed" seems pretty self evident. You need to install a suitable version of cupy